# How to retrieve the latest modified tasks using REST API?

Tags: python, rally

I am creating a integration tool to integrate with rally and my web application. I decided to use Python to run in my web-server to retrieve the contents from rally.

In one of the scenario, I need to get the last modified task from a story. I don't know the ID, Name or anything, but I know the story name. Using the story name, how can I get the last modified task(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how to set up Kyle's query in pyral:

```
server = "rally1.rallydev.com"
user = "user@company.com"
password = "topsecret"
workspace = "My Workspace"
project = "My Project"
rally = Rally(server, user, password, workspace=workspace, project=project)
rally.enableLogging("rally.history.showtasks")

fields    = "FormattedID,State,Name,WorkProduct,Name,LastUpdateDate",
criterion = 'Workproduct.Name = "My Tasks User Story"'

response = rally.get('Task', fetch=fields, query=criterion, order="LastUpdateDate Desc",pagesize=200, limit=400)

most_current_task = response.next()
print "%-8.8s  %-52.52s  %s" % (most_current_task.FormattedID, most_current_task.Name, most_current_task.State)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with how to use pyral but you should be able to get what you'd like by querying against the task wsapi endpoint like so:

```
/slm/webservice/1.40/task.js?query=(WorkProduct.Name = "Story Name")&order=LastUpdateDate DESC
```

Now you just need to get pyral to generate that request.  :-)